# Need help simplifying or improving a weighted distribution formula in excel (math/excel/programming noob)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I've been having some fun creating a rather extensive inventory in Google Sheets for my collection of trading cards. I buy the majority of my collectibles in **lots** meaning that I pay a total of X dollars for Y number of cards of different values (as opposed to buying each card individually).

In my spreadsheet I have a "Purchase Price" column where I enter in the price I paid for each card. If I buy 1 lot of 10 cards, to find the value of each of those cards you would just divide the cost of the lot by the number of cards in the lot. So if I purchased 1 lot of 10 cards for a total of $100, the Purchase Price of each card would equal $10. Simple enough right?

Well, that *would* be if you were OK with entering the rare, uncommon, and common cards in the lot with having the same exact purchase price even though their real market values would all be different. So, what I did was create a formula that automatically adjusts the purchase price for each card that's part of a lot based on its rarity so it's at least closer in accuracy to the actual market value of the card.

Here is the formula:

```
=IFS(B2="C",D2*$B$15*G2/((D2*$B$15)+(E2*$B$16)+(F2*$B$17))/D2,
     B2="U",D2*$B$16*G2/((D2*$B$15)+(E2*$B$16)+(F2*$B$17))/D2,
     B2="R",D2*$B$17*G2/((D2*$B$15)+(E2*$B$16)+(F2*$B$17))/D2)
```

Not sure if that means much to anyone, so [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NeAJ7dkAKtgcNBVVHy_0MyRWpqkXYiTXX_5BqybQSsU/edit?usp=sharing)'s a link to an example spreadsheet of the formula in action below.

And if you don't care to check *that* out, here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of formula in action]

**The problem:**

So the formula works exactly how I want it to work **EXCEPT when there are 0 commons in a lot**. When that happens I get a **#DIV/0!** error saying that **"Function DIVIDE parameter 2 cannot be zero."** I understand why this is happening since it doesn't like to divide by 0 in the first line, but what I don't understand is how to fix it.

How can I fix the DIV error, or is there a better way to do this, perhaps an alternative formula or approach? I am not a programmer and somewhat of a beginner at Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise this is more a comment than an answer, but it's too large to put it as a comment:

Your formula is unreadable, as you can see:

```
=IFS(B2="C",D2*$B$15*G2/((D2*$B$15)+(E2*$B$16)+(F2*$B$17))/D2,
     B2="U",D2*$B$16*G2/((D2*$B$15)+(E2*$B$16)+(F2*$B$17))/D2,
     B2="R",D2*$B$17*G2/((D2*$B$15)+(E2*$B$16)+(F2*$B$17))/D2)
```

First I'd advise you to create a new column (you might always [hide it](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Hide-or-show-rows-or-columns-659c2cad-802e-44ee-a614-dde8443579f8)), `I:I`, which contains following formula (for `I2`):

```
=B2*G2/((D2*const_weigth_common)+(E2*const_weigth_uncommon)+(F2*const_weigth_rare))/D2
```

(And you give this a meaningful header name)

As far as names for `$B$15:$B$17` are concerned, do something like:

```
$B$15 : const_weigth_common
$B$16 : const_weigth_uncommon
$B$17 : const_weigth_rare
```

(You do know how to use [names in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)?)

Like this, your formula becomes:

```
=IFS(B2="C",I2 * const_weigth_common,
     B2="U",I2 * const_weigth_uncommon,
     B2="R",I2 * const_weigth_rare);
```

As far as your error is concerned: as mentioned in another answer, this might be tackled using the `=IF()` formula, so `I2` becomes:

```
=IF(D2<>0;...;_ERROR_VALUE); // up to you how to change your error value
```

Like this, your formulas become much clearer and it will be easier to solve possible problems.

Comment: I think you meant D2 instead of B2 at the start of the I column formula right? Thanks for the naming suggestion, it definitely makes things a lot more readable. However, I'm still not entirely sure how to solve the DIV error. I think there's a fundamental problem with the formula itself since the end of each line divides by D2 which if it's 0, the whole formula breaks. I'll have to figure out a different formula I think. Let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions.

1. Embed each division in an IFERROR() function as shown below. This function will return zero instead of an error. You can substitute another calculation for that. In fact, depending upon which level you introduce the IFERROR at (embracing just one of the three calculations or all three) you might choose to embed the IFS in another IFS that tests for zeroes. Once you have no more divisions by zero there would be no more need for IFERROR. So, it becomes a question of formula efficiency.

   =IFERROR(D2*$B$15*G2/((D2*$B$15)+(E2*$B$16)+(F2*$B$17))/D2,0)
2. Forget about all of this and seek a commercially logical solution. The logic says that you never buy a lot unless it contains some items you want, and the seller never has a lot that doesn't contain rubbish. In the end you get inundated with *commons*, meaning you have more of them than you can ever hope to sell. So, what's their real, commercial value? Valuate your rare and uncommon cards individually and all the baggage not at all. You will find the outcome more realistic both for the *Commons* and the *Rare*. BTW, that's what they do with stamp or coin collections.

Answer (score 1):

## *I Ain't  No Math-A-Magician*

---

*But I can help you with this...*

---

> *The way I see it, **there are three schools of thought** and you need to figure out **which one is yours:***

1. ***The programmer*** - trapping #div/0 errors all day
2. ***The purist*** - there is only one answer, and it is undefined
3. ***The pragmatic*** -  a graph shows results approaching a limit

---

- **I think the programmer is either dangerous or ineffectual, or dangerously ineffectual.**  Sure he can trap there error but what exactly does that do?  I'll tell you exactly what that does, it puts lipstick on a pig.  It's literally replacing one string, "#div/0!", with a different more aesthetic string.  Or he can play second fiddle to the devil and publicly killing the one bug everyone knew how to defend at defend sgainst and creating another?
- **I think the purist is right about one thing, the answer is what it is and it can't be a anything else; but he's also wrong.**  A precisely known theoretical answer may very well be undefined, but where in the real world has anyone ever seen division by zero?  It's a mathematical construct like infinity, we can safely ignore it.  Don't believe me?  What happens when you dvide the sun by zero? Go ahead, I'll wait for your answer.
- **I think these things because I am grounded in pragmatism**  One string is not better than the other if they both symbolize an attempt to divide by zero.  I prefer knowing who my enemies are so I my keep them in front of it me.  Nature truly abhorss the undefined and is only slightly displeased with a vacuum.